# Xcode "link with editor" option?

Tags: xcode

There is an option in Eclipse, which when activated, updates the selection in the project navigator, according to currently opened / focused file. In Eclipse this is a button in the project navigator called "link with editor".

Is there something similar in Xcode?

Comment: can you elaborate "updates the selection"

Comment: It will show like you have opened the file from there - expand directories and show the filename hovered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Eclipse:

[what does "link with editor " feature do in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333875/what-does-link-with-editor-feature-do-in-eclipse)

Link with editor is useful when you open many files in your project. When you select a file in the editor, the Project Explorer or the Navigator show you the same file in its document tree.

In XCode,
 **Reveal in Project Navigator** Keyboard shortcut is <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

Even **right click** on the file will give you the option to Reveal.

Comment: Ah, perfect! Not exactly the same functionality, since you have to press that each time, but I think it's even better, since you don't always want the navigator to update.